# In javascript tag, show comma instead of dot in ajax/jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code inside javascript tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
     $.ajax({
            ...

            success: function (result) {
                result.TableName.forEach(
                    function (item) {
                        table.append("<tr>" +
                            "<td><label>" + item.X + "</label></td>" +
                            "<td><input id='X_" + item.Id + "' name='X_" + item.Id +"' type='text' value=" + item.X + "></td>"
```

its value item.X has a string value with dot (`.`). However, I want to use comma (`,`) instead of a dot in cshtml file. 
Using comma should not affect the source of data but the user should see the data with a comma.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd be much better off not hardcoding HTML concatenation like that. Instead of retrieving the values and manually building the HTML, make the controller return a partial view

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?! `item.X.replace(".",",")`

Comment: using comma should not affect the source of data but the user should see the data with a comma. I hope now it is clear for all of us.

Comment: @alighasemzad it does not work!

Comment: What data? Where? Are you talking perhaps about numeric data that needs to be formatted? Please [edit] your code to be much more specific, ideally showing what inputs you have to the code, what outputs you have, and what is wrong with the outputs.

Comment: then you need to be more specific about the data. If by "it does not work!" you mean the data itself is changed and you don't want to, simply just create a temp variable and change the "value of the temp"  and show that to user!

Answer (score 1):

It's still not clear to me what the .X does and if the string where you want to replace dot with comma is in the `item` var,
anyway let's say you have a var, containing a string with a *dot* and you want a *comma* instead, you have to use **replace** like so:

to replace a single dot with a comma:

```
item = item.replace('.', ',');
```

to replace all dots with commas:

```
item = item.replace(/./g, ',');
```

do this before the ajax starts (outside of it), then you can leave your code as it is.

Answer (score -1):

item.X looks like having string value but it does not behave like a string. That's why I wanted to be sure so I use this:

```
item.X.toString().replace(".", ",");
```

It is not the best solution but it works now! I am waiting for your best solutions.

Comment: " looks like having string value but it does not behave like a string"...no idea what you mean by this. Strings are strings. What behaviour are you talking about exactly? Are you claiming this value contravenes the specification in some way?